# PHP sending 7 emails to end up and hit 1 mobile sms carrier

Tags: php, email, sms

This is a new questions, that I figured deserved a new thread.

I have a php for that is sending an SMS to the mobileNumber@carrier.com

This is working.

I have to ask the user to input his number and to choose his provider, I was wondering since in my area NEW YORK, we only have about 7 popular mobile providers.

Can I skip that second question of asking the user what mobile provider.

And then just send with php all 7 emails out with the number and each mobile carriers email extention to wind up with hitting one of them?

for instance, instead of sending

`mail(1231233321@txt.att.net, $subject, $message )`;

can I send all 7 at once? Knowing 6 wont work..

```
mail(1231231233@txt.att.net, 1231231233@tmobile.net, etc....., $subject, $message );
```

And if so How would I go about writing it with this attached code?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){error("Must use form to get here!");}
$ph = preg_replace('/[^[:digit:]]/', '', $_POST['10digit']);
$carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
switch ($carrier){
    case 'att':
        $to = $ph . '@txt.att.net';
        break;
    case 'metropcs':
        $to = $ph . '@mymetropcs.com';
        break;
    case 'nextel':
        $to = $ph . '@messaging.nextel.com';
        break;
    case 'sprint':
        $to = $ph . '@messaging.sprintpcs.com';
        break;
    case 'tmobile':
        $to = $ph . '@tmomail.net';
        break;
    case 'verizon':
        $to = $ph . '@vtext.com';
        break;
    case 'virgin':
        $to = $ph . '@vmobl.com';
        break;      
    default:
        error("No carrier selected, message not sent!");
}

$subject = "Buseto's Pizzeria";
$message = "1851 Sunrise Highway, Bay Shore, NY 11706 (631) 665-4939 http://www.busetopizza.com";

mail($to, $subject, $message);
    echo "Your message has been sent!";
    exit();
function error($msg){
    echo "An error has occurred: ".$msg;
    exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPAM emails are the primary reason the internet is not as fast as it could be. Do you really want to be contributing 6 times the amount of emails you *should* send just to remove the need for one little drop-down?

To answer the question, multiple recipients can be specified by separating them correctly, which if memory serves is done with a semicolon. So your `to` parameter will look like `"test@example.com;other@example2.com"`.

Comment: I am not trying to spam, so i will take that into considerationg. But this form will be used like a couple times a month. I don't think I will be boggin anything down. I feel like I will be delivering a smoother user experience.

Answer (score 1):

The carrier email -> SMS bridges are not particularly robust. If sending SMSes is important to your business, using something like [Twilio's SMS API](http://www.twilio.com/api/sms) might be a good idea. (If your business is indeed a pizzeria, their telephone APIs might also be of interest!)